# How to get above DocumentRoot for scripting purposes?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

How do I get a javascript ajax call to look in the directory at the same level as the DocumentRoot?

I keep getting pushed into the DocumentRoot.

In httpd.conf, I have my DocumentRoot set like so:

```
DocumentRoot = "/var/www/html/wordpress"
```

So, when a user accesses www.mysite.com, it directs them to the www.mysite.com/wordpress folder but they don't see the "wordpress".

But, my legacy software already has a folder setup under html (the same level as wordpress) called "scripts" like so:

```
html/
    /wordpress  <--- DocumentRoot
    /scripts    <--- i need to get in here via ajax
```

So, when I  try to access it from an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../scripts/myScript.js"
});
```

apache (correctly so) sends it to wordpress so my actual call looks like:

```
"192.168.2.2/wordpress/scripts/myScript.js"
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
"192.168.2.2/scripts/myScript.js"
```

this is the path:

```
"/var/www/html/scripts/myScript.js"
```

I'm assuming there is a virtualhost or redirect directive that should do the trick but I've tried several versions and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path:

```
$.ajax({url: "/scripts/myScript.js"});
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can use absolute paths in ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275262/jquery-ajax-full-server-path

Comment: You can most certainly use absolute paths.