# Ajax call can't find url because the .php is removed in URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess

As the title says, my **AJAX POST call** can't seem to find its URL. This is the because in the **.htaccess** file i removed the **.php** from the URL's of my website.

**The obvious error**

```
http://localhost/style-faq/includes/handlers/ajax/giveView 404 (Not Found)
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/myWebsite/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/myWebsite/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

**AJAX POST call**

```
function giveView(id){
    $.post("includes/handlers/ajax/giveView.php", //already tried without .php
                {
                    id: id
                })

                .done(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                })
}
```

Is there a way to give the **AJAX** call the right url? Or is the only solution to just get rid of the **.htaccess** code and live a life with seeing **.php** in the URL.

Comment: This might be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550374/using-ajax-to-access-file-without-extension?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You need to fine-tune the last rule to make sure it also includes paths to existing php files that are located in sub-directories.